# ggplot time series drop date and aligning time axis based on hours

Tags: ggplot2, time-series

I have a data frame with three variables, Name, Heart_rate, Time

```
    df  %>%  str
     $ Name     : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
     $ Heart_rate: num  77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 78 ...
     $ Time      : POSIXct, format: "2021-08-30 06:56:41"
```

and trying to plot using ggplot.

```
    df %>% ggplot(aes(Time, Heart_rate, color=Name)) +geom_line()
```

[The result is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkiRn.png)
The problem is those heart rates were measured on different days. I want to plot three person's heart rate time series based only on hours, minutes and seconds, dropping dates(ymd). I tried facet_wrap and scales free option, but the time axis does not match perfectly.

```
    df %>% ggplot(aes(Time, Heart_rate, color=Name)) +geom_line() + facet_wrap(~Name,scales="free_x", nrow=3)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUHjx.png)

Do you have better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My way is to define new POSIXct type Time by choosing an arbitrary day.

```
 df %>% mutate(Time2= as.Date('2022-01-01') +hms(Time %>% format(format='%H:%M:%S'))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Time2, Heart_rate, color=Name)) +geom_line()
```